# Recursion with string::find()

Tags: c++, recursion, find

first off I would like to say that yes this is a homework assignment, though I am not asking you to do it for me, but rather asking for help in why it is crashing. It is a recursion problem to write a function `subCount()` that takes two string parameters `"str"` and `"sub"`, and checks how many times `"sub"` appears in `"str"`, returning an int. You must use recursion.
Here is my code with `<string>` and `std` namespace.

```
int subCount(const string& str, const string& sub)
{
    if (str.find(sub != string::npos))
    {
        return 1 + subCount(str.substr(1, str.length()), sub);
    }   
    else 
    {
        return subCount(str.substr(1, str.length()), sub);
    }
}
```

It builds fine(using visual studio 2012), but crashes when trying to run. I suspect that I am not using the `find()` function correctly, but I can't make much sense of the reference on  cplusplus.com, which for string parameters is `"size_t find (const string& str, size_t pos = 0) const noexcept;"`. Currently, my understanding of `find()` is if `"sub"` is in `str`, then it returns true, causing `return 1 + subCount(str.substr(1), sub);` to execute, and if its not, then the other return statement. If it is not a problem with the `find()` function please say so and what the problem is, not how to fix it though. Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you function crashed because of <del>[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) (most often reason why recursive function crashed)</del> `substr` on empty string.

all branches of your function recursively call itself and can never stop.

you need to check the is `str` an empty string and return 0 if it is. Since this is a homework so I won't post working code for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the use of find function. I am not able to compile your function.

Requirement is to search number of times a pattern appears in a string using recursion.

Solution:

1. You should use find func but remember find func returns the position of where it finds the pattern, so after every successful find() you will have to skip the part searched and search in remaining string.
2. Use the correct syntax of find.

> str.find(sub != string::npos) 
>   // This is wrong.

Comment: Thankyou for answering, however I figured it out about 20 minutes ago. I had been excited when I found the find() function so I was trying to use it without realizing that it checked if `sub` was in `str` at all, instead of at the beginning of `str` where I wanted it to be. As for the syntax, I edited that part in to the wrong place but it was correct in my code `str.find(sub) != string::npos`. Thanks anyways for looking at this.